# Importing a PDF the words are incorrectly recognised and glued together

Tags: import, pdf-format

As a reproducible example to demonstrate the problem, I will consider a simple pdf document produced by the following tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext    
\end{document}
```

Let the corresponding pdf be `test.pdf`.

Trying to import this pdf in Mathematica I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, the words are all glued together.
This is confirmed by the result of exporting this back to pdf, which results in the following:

[image]

The spacings are obviously all messed up.

Is there a way to avoid this? Why does this problem arise?

Comment: @BobHanlon not sure I follow what's your point.. you are generating the text with Mathematica and then exporting it, how does that relate to my problem? I chose the Lorem Ipsum text just as  an example of the problem

Comment: @BobHanlon I guess I could have been more clear. I'm specifically asking how to overcome problems like the one I showed, arising when you want to import a pdf *not* produced by Mathematica.

Comment: On my machine (`$Version==11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)`) I get an error message "Import::general: Expected cross reference table" and nothing is imported

Comment: @yohbs interesting. I'm on v11.0.1 for windows 64-bit. I got that error message when trying to import other pdfs, like with this: `Import["http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.\
pdf", "PDF"]`. I get yet different errors on other pdf files, like for the following: `Import["http://www.tra.org.bh/media/document/sample10.pdf", "PDF"]` which gives me an `Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject` error

Comment: In that case you might want to consider filing a bug report to Wolfram support